# Magento, hide the toolbar only in a specific block

Tags: php, block, footer, toolbar, magento-1.9

I'm trying to hide the toolbar of the products only in the block footer but without success. I have tried using the function

`<?php if(Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlockName () != "footer"): ?>`

but it returned an error. I do not want me to hide the toolbar across the page, but only in a specific block.
How can I hide the toolbar in a specific block?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Add your error to see what's going on

Comment: The error is that it does not make me see more footer.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove block using chenging layout xml,add like as below in your local.xml file

```
  <reference name="footer">
    <remove name="block name" /> 
 </reference>
```

This URL have more details about local.xml
  http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/5-useful-tricks-for-your-magento-local-xml/

Comment: Why? Because my problem is that i want hide the toolbar of the products in footer. Not in the entire page.

Comment: @Gabriel91 ,Have you include a list of products in the footer?

Comment: Actually your question is not clear ,We think you need to remove one block from the footer,

Comment: Explain little more,How yo included product list in your footer will be more helpfull

Comment: Sorry if I was not very clear. I have my own blog page of my site in Magento. I would like to hide the toolbar of the products only in the footer and not the entire page blog.

Comment: @Shijin totally agree on your way to do it, but I guess this is the case of the same block being displayed twice as a child of the same block.

Answer (score 0):

Although I would suggest doing most of those kind of task in the layout, as [Shijin is proposing it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29891578/2123530). If you tried it that way and for some reason cannot do it properly in the layout, you can use the method `getNameInLayout` available for any block extending `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract`

```
<?php if($this->getNameInLayout() != "footer"): ?>
```

Comment: I try with this function but the result unfortunately the result not change. I try with this but without success: `<?php if(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getModuleName() != 'cms' && $this->getNameInLayout() != "footer"): ?>`

Comment: try to display `$this->getNameInLayout()` I guess you actually are not on the block footer.

Comment: You were right. The block is not called "footer" but "footer_new_products". But I tried to put your code but still the toolbar not disappears. `<?php if(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getModuleName() != 'cms' && $this->getNameInLayout() != "footer_new_products"): ?>`

Comment: Are you sure of the other part of your condition, are you also sure about what your `if():` and `endif;` does surround is what you want to remove ?

Comment: Yes, bacuse in the other pages with first condition the toolbar is hide but not in the footer of my page "blog". With the second condition not hide the toolbar in the block footer_new_products. I can not understand why. How else could I do?

Comment: That is because the other pages are cms, and your blog is not a cms page what you actually want to do is : `<?php if(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getModuleName() != 'cms' || $this->getNameInLayout() != "footer_new_products"): ?>`. But I really recommend you not doing it like that but like Shijin is proposing you to do. What you only have to do is find the handles of the pages where you want to remove this block.

Comment: Now i understand. But I can not recall the name of the block of the toolbar. When I insert the code getNameInLayout () returns me a series of numbers (eg: 0.79122400 1430131924) and not the name of the block. Why? Thank you.